# QR codes visible in "The Talos Principle" that shouldn't be

Tags: the-talos-principle

Apparently you're supposed to be able to "leave your mark" for anybody in your steam friends list, which they can then read. Having just joined, I have yet to add anybody. Yet, somehow, I'm seeing QR codes everywhere from people I don't know. What's going on, and can I turn this off? It's super distracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some QR codes are already present as part of the game's plot.

And no, you can't disable them.

Comment: I became concerned when I saw four QR codes on the side of building A. One said: "Hey, he promised me the world as well! What a joker!" Another talked about how the message materialized on the wall in front of them. Another was complaining about some sort of time stamp. Anyway, they just seemed like the sort of messages players would write, rather than NPCs. But, maybe that's the idea.

Comment: @AaronF Players can't actually just write whatever they want.  They have a set number of prompts they can choose from when they use the paint can.

Comment: @AaronF: Yep, those are part of the plot.